# Why does the voltage of a 18650 battery drop when connected to an LM2596 module?

Tags: batteries, buck, lithium-ion

[image: Basic Schematic for the circuit and measure point]

I am trying to get a 5V output out of a 2S 18650 cells (getting a 7.5V from them.)

I am trying to use a LM2596 module, but as soon as the battery is connected to the LM2596, the input reading goes down to 2.5V. The LM2596 does not work with this voltage as expected. I also tried using an Arduino 5V as the input to the LM2596 and it works as expected, bringing the voltage down. This is being tested without any load at the output as I have to first regulate it.

Why does this happen with the 18650 batteries?

Comment: Could you post a schematic? Did you measure the voltage directly at the poles of the batteries?

Comment: If you are clamping down you batteries to 2.5 V, you will either have a fire very quickly or the batteries have tremendous high ESR.

Comment: @winny Or the battery protection system doesn't like what you're doing, and acts as a very high ESR.

Comment: _"getting a 7.5V from them"_ - that voltage indicates the batteries are nearly flat. What is the voltage on each cell? What voltage do you get after fully charging them?

Comment: Some batteries have 18650 type, but may have protection chip inside. They may be longer,  approximately 70 mm. Protection may be activated.

Comment: @StarCat there really isn't much of a schematic, it's just the 2 batteries in a pack and the Lm2596 module

Comment: @BruceAbbott being in a pack i'm not reading them separately as i'd rather not unmake the pack unless necessary. that said, these are 3,7v batteries individually so they should be 7,4v usually, so getting 7,5 from the would they aren't flat right?

Comment: @StarCat sorry, i forgot to mention that it is the LM2596 module and not just the chip, edited the post

Comment: Please post a schematic along with where you measured 2.5 V.

Comment: 3.75V is the storage and selling voltage of a Lithium battery that is almost dead. The fully charged voltage of each cell is 4.2V for a total of 8.4V for two series battery cells.

Comment: @winny added schematic, it's very barebones as i just want to get the 5V out of the LM2596 before connecting other components

Comment: Exactly which 7.4V 2S 18650 battery pack do you have, and where did you get it from? Does it have a PCM (protection circuit module) inside? Show us a photo of your setup.

Comment: i got it in a brazilian equivalent of ebay: https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1793278177-bateria-li-ion-18650-74v-2200mah-sanyo-c-bms-carregador-_JM the seller has supposedly good reputation. i cannot however see wether it has protection or not altough the seller does state it has it.

Comment: Either the cells are not fully charged, or they are not "activated" if they contain protection circuit. Try to charge them separately with 4.2 V, this often enables internal circuits... they must show at least 7 V or better up to 8.4V beforehand. Maybe the regulator draw a too large inrush current and triggers the cell protection?

Answer (score 1):

This fake 18650 battery cell is why we ask where did you get them from:
[image: fake]

Comment: i got it in a brazilian equivalent of ebay: https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1793278177-bateria-li-ion-18650-74v-2200mah-sanyo-c-bms-carregador-_JM
the seller has supposedly good reputation. i cannot however see wether it has protection or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Lithium-Ion rechargeable battery cells in series but they are not charged. They will produce 8.4V when they are properly charged.